# Request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: http-headers, request, angular

I am just trying to use `mocky.io` from my `http://localhost:8080`

But getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mocky.io/v2/5715f13a1100004d1187d9e1. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

My request looking like that:

```
let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  this.people = http.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5715f13a1100004d1187d9e1', { headers: headers })
    .map(response => response.json());
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should setup the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in mocky.io.
Just click on "Switch to Advanced mode" and you will see a "custom headers" input. Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and put `*` as its value. Then create your mocky.io url. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

It is looks like you are trying to access to other domain.
Maybe add this in the web.config?

```
<httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />   </customHeaders> </httpProtocol>
```